# Problems with DefaultServlet

Tags: java, servlets, jetty

I have embedded jetty server in my app and using WebAppContext to return static files (.html, .png, etc.) and to store servlets. When I try to get static from browser, I'm getting 503 error caused by exception, but servlets works fine. As I understood from stack trace WebAppContext tried to use DefaultServlet to return static files. I tried set DefaultServlet to "/*" path and still got that exception. Is there another ways to return static files by WebAppContext withouth DefaultServlet?

I tried ResourceHandler instead of WebAppContext, it works fine but ignores jetty login constraints (Also tried to turn on with WebAppContext and withouth constraints and got the same error)

Exception:

```
2019-03-31 18:14:28.344:WARN:oejs.ServletHandler:qtp129498568-21: Error for /reg.html
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpContent.getContentLength()J
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet.sendData(DefaultServlet.java:865)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet.doGet(DefaultServlet.java:531)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:781)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:553)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1126)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1060)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:509)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:288)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:539)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:540)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Code:

```
    Server server = new Server(8080);

    String htmlResourcesPath = "web";

    WebAppContext webAppContext = new WebAppContext();
    webAppContext.setContextPath("/");
    webAppContext.setResourceBase(htmlResourcesPath);
    webAppContext.setParentLoaderPriority(true);

    webAppContext.addServlet(RedirectServlet.class, "");
    webAppContext.addServlet(RegisterServlet.class, "/reg");
    webAppContext.addServlet(AuthServlet.class, "/auth");

    server.setHandler(webAppContext);
```

Comment: The error you get means that you're using several jetty jars that are not compatible with each other: the class org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet tries to call a method getContentLength() which doesn't exist in the class org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpContent. You need to fix your dependencies.

Comment: I'm using only embedded jetty lib and maven jetty plugin. They can conflict with each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpContent.getContentLength()J

You have mismatched versions of Jetty JAR files.

Make sure you only have 1 version of all Jetty JAR files in your project.

If you are using `embedded-jetty` then you would not be using `jetty-maven-plugin`, so pick one or the other, but not both.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for help. Just to specify:

I used 2 jetty versions:

```
<!--dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
    <version>9.3.0.M1</version>
</dependency-->

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
    <version>9.3.0.M0</version>
</dependency>
```

I thought that jetty-webapp complements jetty-server, but they are separate libs that conflicts with each other